# Project doesn't get compiled with Java 17 after upgrading Oracle aqapi to aqapi-jakarta

Tags: java, ojdbc, advanced-queuing

Upgrade from Spring 5 to Spring 6 (Spring Boot v2 — v3) brings Jakarta EE 9+ with it. This makes `com.oracle.database.messaging:aqapi` to be incompatible because the `ConnectionFactory` class moved from `javax` package to `jakarta` package.

This one can be solved by replacing the `com.oracle.database.messaging:aqapi` with `com.oracle.database.messaging:aqapi-jakarta` dependency.

But after this replacement the project doesn't get compiled with the error: `createShardingKeyBuilder() in cannot implement createShardingKeyBuilder() in javax.sql.CommonDataSource return type oracle.jdbc.OracleShardingKeyBuilder is not compatible with java.sql.ShardingKeyBuilder` or it can be `createShardingKeyBuilder in oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource clashes with createShardingKeyBuilder  in javax.sql.CommonDataSource`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in `com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc` dependency.

`com.oracle.database.messaging:aqapi-jakarta` is depended on `com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8` but to make Oracle JDBC work under Java17 one needs `com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11`.

Thus the `pom.xml` should have the dependencies specified in the following way:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.messaging</groupId>
      <artifactId>aqapi-jakarta</artifactId>
      <version>23.2.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
      <version>23.2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```